# Что такое Code Review, как это фактически происходит?

Tags: инспекция-кода, agile

Это некоторые собрания вживую когда написавший код рассказывает что он делал а другие задают вопросы или нечто другое? смотрел публикации на хабре и других ресурсах по этой теме, но там все очень обобщенно и вскользь. с кучей хвалебных отзывов но не раскрывают фактическую суть понятия. Знакомый с курсов говорит, что у них Code Review, это когда кто-то из менторов/преподователей через онлайн смотрит твой код и дает по ходу просмотра коментарии. Какая из трактовок наиболее правильная?

Comment: это когда кто-то из менторов/преподователей через онлайн смотрит твой код и дает по ходу просмотра коментарии, а также указывает на ошибки и проч. для улучшения кода

Comment: На этот вопрос не существует правильного ответа. Процесс рецензии кода чрезвычайно отличается от команды к команде.

Answer (score 6):

что именно происходит на code review сильно зависит от компании. К примеру, там где я работаю сейчас, ревью делает любой разработчик, который свободен в это время. Он проверяет следующее:

- в коде нет конфиденциальной информации, такой как пароли (они должны быть в конфигах), имена разработчиков или чего то подобного
- в коде нет явных глупостей: бесконечных циклов, "заката солнца вручную".
- код понятен (хотя этим иногда пренебрегают, а иногда нужно объяснить свое решение).
- в коде нет бекдоров/вирусов и подобного.
- стиль. Но тут все очень индивидуально и некоторые считают, что их чувство прекрасного лучше, чем оффициальные гайды.

Как происходит сам процесс:

- разработчик делает себе ветку и там пишет код. Код обязательно пушится, но не мерджится в основную ветку.
- делается дифф изменений и отправляется на специальный адрес внутренней рассылки. Также в письмо добавляет краткое объяснение "что и почему сделано", буквально одно-два предложения.
- другие разработчики просматривают почту или специальный внутренний сайт, на который диффы попадают автоматом через почту (сейчас планируем сделать, что бы они вытягивались с гита автоматом).
- Если другие согласны с кодом, отправляют "+1", если нет - минус и объяснение почему.
- если пплюс получен и пройдено тестирование, код мерждится в мастер.
- когда все выкатывается в релиз, специальный код проверяет, что на каждый мердж был получен +1.

Answer (score 3):

Конкретный способ проведения review кода - это технические детали. Главное - это сам смысл этой процедуры, заключающийся в том, что код, написанный разработчиком, должен быть проверен кем-то еще для приведения его к некоему общему знаменателю (например, соблюдение тех или иных соглашений, принятых в команде) и поиска ошибок/уязвимых мест/каких-либо проблем.

Скажем, на первой моей работе обзор кода выполнялся так: разработчики собирались вместе и поочередно смотрели код каждого из них, в случае нахождения тех или иных проблем критиковали его, что-то предлагали для улучшения и всячески спорили. Такой подход с одной стороны несколько сложноват - нужно всех собрать, выслушать мнение каждого, потратить время на обсуждение, но с другой стороны позволяет каждому расти профессионально (в споре рождается истина как известно) и вообще довольно демократичен.
 На другой работе ревью не было вовсе (что наверное неправильно), на еще одной работе ведущий разработчик смотрел код, попадающий в коммит и самолично принимал решение относительно правильности/неправильности тех или иных его участков.

Answer (score 1):

Любая. Кто как может, так и проводит.

Как вариант, есть онлайн-система, которая следит за коммитами в систему контроля версий. При этом, к каждому коммиту приписывается фраза, к какому ревью его отнести. Потом человек добавляет нужных ревьюверов в список и запускает ревью. Соответственно, они либо подтверждают, что всё хорошо, либо добавляют замечания. Когда все ревьюверы подтвердят, что всё хорошо ревью закрывается.

Если рассматривать ситуацию, что разработка велась в отдельной ветке (что может требоваться правилами), то после закрытия ревью, изменения из неё вносятся в основную ветку.

Answer (score 0):

А давайте переведем этот термин на русский, что бы было понятнее, о чем вообще идет речь. Итак, что такое "Code Review" или же "Пересмотр исходного кода"? Это когда Вы или Ваши коллеги пересматриваете исходный код и начинаете думать, как его улучшить и нет ли в нем опасных мест, ошибок и выискиваете способы улучшения его качества.

Тут стоит учесть, что пересматривать самому в краткосрочный период после написания довольно глупо, иначе бы Вы исправили потенциальные ошибки еще во время написания. Поэтому обычно это делают Ваши коллеги. Как они это делают, в общем-то, дело личного вкуса и удобства.

Comment: скорее "Обзор кода"

Answer (score -2):

Вот у @KoVadim круто!

А у меня нигде за 35 лет подобного не было. Намеревались, конечно же, сделать (в начале каждой очередной разработки) формальную процедуру  почти во всех командах, а на практике вечно ни у кого нет то времени, то желания.

Поэтому практически все ревью кода сводились к абсолютно неформальному и нерегулярному -- "слушай, что-то мой (или твой) кусок фигово работает, давай посмотрим..."